# Django - Is it possible to get objects of "indirectly related one to one field" with reverse_many_to_one_manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

For instance I have these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I can easily get all the profiles for a company using the following query:

```
Company.objects.first().profile_set.all()
```

But is there a way I can get the related users from company instead of profile, keeping in mind that a user object is one to one related with profile object?

**Note:** These models are just example models, and keeping in view the application logic, we can't combine user and profile model.

Answer (score 1):

`company = Company.objects.get(id=X)`

`User.objects.filter(profile__company=company)`

or create a manager on Users:

```py
def from_company(self, company: Company):
    return self.filter(profile__company=company)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Thanks for the solution - but I am looking for a way to fetch linked users from company object rather than this approach.